# Translate plot data from file in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have some `x,y` coordinate data organised as two columns in my `mydata.dat` text file. I have no problem plotting this, but I want to plot the same data but just translated by some 2d Vector. My attempt so far has been something like below but the result is that nothing happens in terms of a shift! Any ideas?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[] plot[] 
    file {mydata.dat};

\begin{scope}[every coordinate/.style={shift={(1,0)}}]
    \draw[thick] plot[] 
        file {mydata.dat};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Edit:

So I tried doing `\draw [xshift = 1cm]` and that seems to work, but still wondering why my first try didn't work.

Comment: coordinate is a special TikZ shape. Plot data is not.

Comment: OTOH [xshift=1] is (also) a valid scope option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has found a solution himself which he presented as an edit to the question.